# One to Many relashionship in Entity framwork dbcontext

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-core

I have two tables in the database as follows

```
Table Beneficiaries contains ID, Name, and Object of table BeneficiariesGroup as bgroup
Tabel BeneficiariesGroup contains ID, Name
```

So 1 Beneficiary have 1 group and a group contains multiple beneficiaries
How can I modify my OnModelCreating to be able to read the name of the group when declaring a beneficiary

my dbcontext class is the following

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : DbContext
{
    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options) : base(options)
    {            
    }

    public DbSet<Beneficiaries> Beneficiaries { get; set; }
    public DbSet<BeneficiariesGroup> BeneficiariesGroup { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(builder);
        builder.Entity<Beneficiaries>().HasOne<BeneficiariesGroup>(a => a.bgroup).WithMany(b=>b.beneficiary);                           
    }
}
```

Entities:

```
 public class Beneficiaries
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string CUID { get; set; }
    public int GroupID { get; set; }       
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
    public string YearOfBirth { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreationDate { get; set; }
    public CashUnited.Data.Repositories.BeneficiariesGroup.BeneficiariesGroup bgroup { get; set; }

}

 public class BeneficiariesGroup
{
    public int ID { get; set; }      
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ICollection<CashUnited.Data.Repositories.Beneficiaries.Beneficiaries> beneficiary { get; set; }
}
```

I tried the above but it didn't work saying: **Invalid column name 'bgroupID'**

Appreciate your help

Comment: looks like It is a one-to-many relationships not one to one. could you add your entities too?

Comment: sorry it is one to many

Comment: You forget `foreignKey`

Comment: Add `public int bgroupID {get;set;}` to your `Beneficiaries` class. And add `[ForeignKey(nameof(bgroup))]` on top of it.

Comment: @Sora In the deleted question you're asking about *deserialization*. You have to know the format to know which deserializer to use. There are many XML and Json deserializers and all of them offer a generic high-level API. For example, JSON.NET's `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should add a property to keep track of your FKs.

```cs
public class Beneficiaries
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string CUID { get; set; }
    public int GroupID { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
    public string YearOfBirth { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreationDate { get; set; }
    public BeneficiariesGroup bgroup { get; set; }
    public int bgroupId { get; set; } // you need a porperty to keep your fk
}

...

builder.Entity<Beneficiaries>().HasOne(a => a.bgroup)
.WithMany(q => q.beneficiary)
.HasForeignKey(f => f.bgroupId);
```

Comment: I already added a GroupID in my database Table but i understand the syntax now, thank you